# How to open and read a file in Informix

Tags: file, informix

I need to write a stored procedure which reads input from a text file which contains employee records (multiple rows) and compares those values to that in the employee table and edits the row in the employee table if there are any modifications. I am using the [DB Visualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/) tool with connection type as Informix. As I am new to Informix, I don't know how to start.

The scenario is:

I have an Employee table which has fields emp_no, dept_no, fname, lname, crp_id, sal, hours etc.
I have a text file in 'C:\sample.txt' with data

```
111  222 fname lname 3456
112  223 fname2 lname2 3457..
```

I need to read the first line of the text file, get the emp_no(111) and get the particular record from the emp table. Now, check for the other fields and modify if necessary. For Ex, if the first name for emp 111 in emp table is 'fname1' instead of 'fname', I need to update it. And BTW, it is from a text file that I am reading not from an external table.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. We're going to need a lot more information to be able to give much help. For example, what is in the text file? A single chunk of data that needs to be compared with data stored in a TEXT or CLOB column in some table in a database?  Or unloaded data for multiple rows in a table, that need to be loaded into the database so the resulting table can be compared with another? Or something else altogether? Which version of Informix are you using, and on which system? Which programming languages are an option? Etc.

Comment: Please edit your comments into the question; you can get the full range of formatting options there, which will make it easier for everyone to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using a recent enough version of Informix (12.10, or 11.70), then you should probably be looking to map the file to an external table, and then using the MERGE command to merge the updates and inserts (and possibly deletes) from the external table into the new table.  In theory, that's about 5 SQL commands:

```
BEGIN WORK;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mergeable_data (...) ...;
MERGE ... YourMainTable ... FROM mergeable_data
    ON MATCH UPDATE ...
    ON NO MATCH INSERT ...;  -- Check the syntax; I'm inventing on the fly!
COMMIT WORK;
DROP TABLE mergeable_data;
```

The BEGIN and COMMIT aren't necessary if you have a non-logged database (but why?). On the whole though, your database should be logged.  You could place the COMMIT after the DROP; you could need another COMMIT after the DROP if you have a MODE ANSI database.

- [IDS 12.10 Information Centre](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/informix/v121/index.jsp)
- [CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/informix/v121/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.sqls.doc%2Fids_sqs_2053.htm)
- [MERGE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/informix/v121/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.sqls.doc%2Fids_sqs_2030.htm)

---

Given the extra information now in the question, I am more convinced than ever that using CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE that specifies the file you've got on disk as the data source and the MERGE statement is exactly what you need.  The CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE statement allows IDS to treat the file as if it was a table.  The MERGE statement automatically (with no programming on your part) does things like 'update the first name because it is different'.

You can do it in another way if you wish — be my guest.  Are you using Informix 4GL (I4GL) or some other language?  I4GL is a separate product that must be purchased, and creates compiled programs that run against the database. I've no idea how DB Visualizer would fit into that system.  If you are using I4GL, you can create your temporary table and then (probably) load the data into it, and then do your matching work.  Or you could use CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE and MERGE in SQL ... END SQL blocks.

I'm sure it is confusing for you, too; you're not terribly familiar with Informix and you're not quite sure what you've got and what you're using.  I4GL does not use JDBC at all; it is built atop Informix ESQL/C.  Using plain ESQL/C is another option, but only for masochists like myself (who've been using it for æons).  And even so, I'd still be looking to use CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE and MERGE.

Comment: Thanks. Let me explain it to you in clear.
I am not using Informix tool. I use DB Visualizer with connection type informix and JDBC Informix driver. So, I assumed I should write the script in Informix language(Another language like SQL, Oracle). 

Now, my requirement is not to read from an external table but to read records line by line from a text file, Compare the fields with those in the existing table. 

To start, I want to open the file first & I used " OPEN FILE fd1 FROM "C:\sample.txt" OPTIONS (READ, FORMAT = "CSV")" but it gives me an error. Can you tell me how to open a text file plz.

Comment: The MERGE command can 'do the edit' for you.  Please clarify your question in the question (but comment to let me know you've done so). I'm not clear what DB Visualizer is. I don't know which language you think has an OPEN FILE command; it looks like if might be almost Informix-4GL, but I suspect it isn't. The raw Informix server has no OPEN FILE statement (see the manuals at the Information Centre). At the moment, there's a complete disconnect between you and me — we have no common understanding. I still think CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE and MERGE is a good idea, but some sample data might help.

Comment: Im sorry. I am new to stackoverflow and don't know all the rules. Yes. The open statment is from Informix 4GL. I don't know the difference between 4GL and raw Informix. The scenario is:
I have a text file in 'C:\sample.txt' with data
111  222 fname lname 3456

Comment: Thanks, John. I think creating an Ext table is a good idea. I tried it using 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mergeable_data;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mergeable_data(
        column1         VARCHAR(15)
        )
 USING (
        DATAFILES ('DISK:\C:\sample.txt'),
        FORMAT 'DELIMITED',
        DELUXE
 );
 
It does create the table but when I do select * from mergeable_data, it gives me  [Error Code: -26154, SQL State: IX000]  Could not open file: (file, errno)=(\C\sample.txt,2).  Do you know what the issue might be??

Comment: I have also tried  LOAD FROM 'c:\sample.txt' INSERT INTO test_table ; but it gives me a syntax error

Comment: John, DId you see the comments?

Comment: Yes, I saw them. I don't have the time to work on them for another 4 hours or so. I've also seen the other question.  If you want answers quicker than that, try the ids@iiug.org mailing list.  That is run by the Informix International Users Group (IIUG). I think you have to sign up (but it is free and not onerous), but that's about all.

Comment: Thanks, John. I appreciate the response. Please give your suggestions whenever possible. I will wait. I will also try the other website.