# Loading data from a text file Informix

Tags: informix, loaddata

I want to know if there is any other way to load data from a text file other than using external tables.

Text file looks something like

```
101 fname1 lname1 D01..
102 fname2 lname2 D02..
```

I want to load it into a table with columns emp_id, fname, lname, dept etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Just my opinion... I see the job of load data in two way, from client or from server. From server/database this is something where the DBA/Admin should get be involved because there you are "disturbing" the infrastructure of your system and for good performance and implementation is better use the database tools which your DBA/Admin should support you (for Informix, the options are: **HPL, dbload, dbaccess+load, external tables**). From client side, you can use any tool for that or just write your own tool and use it as your will

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open and read a file in Informix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663446/how-to-open-and-read-a-file-in-informix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ceinmart suggested in comments you can do it from server side or from client side. From server side you can use DB-Access and [`LOAD` command](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/topic/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0883.htm?resultof=%22%6c%6f%61%64%22%20). From client side you can use any tool you like. For such tasks I often use Jython that can use Python string and CSV libraries as well as JDBC database drivers. With Jython you can use `csv` module to read data from file and PreparedStatement to insert it into database. In my other answer: [Substring in Informix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792045/substring-in-informix) you will see such PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 1):

There are three utilities in Informix to load data to the database from flat files:

[Load](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0884.htm) SQL command. Very simple to use, but not very flexible. I would recommend this for small amounts of records (less than 10k)

[Dbload](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.mig.doc/ids_mig_132.htm), which is a command line utility, a bit more complex than the load sql command. This will allow you to have more control on how the records are loaded: commit intervals, starting point in the flat file, number of errors before exiting, etc. I'd recommend this utility for a small to medium sized data loads (>10k<100k).

[HPL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.hpl.doc/hpl.htm), or High Performance Loader, which is a rather complex utility that can load data at a very high rate of speed, but with a lot of overhead. Recommended for large to x-large data loads.