# Substring in Informix

Tags: substring, informix

I need to split a field(Name) into Two (First Name and Last Name) based on a comma in Informix.

Example: "Mark, Wheeler J" has to be split as Mark and Wheeler. I have tried using SQL syntax but it gives me a syntax error in Informix. Please help me.

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(name, 1, CHARINDEX(',', name ) - 1) AS FirstName,
  SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(',', name) + 1, 8000) AS LastName
FROM
 employee
```

Comment: which version are you working: `select dbinfo('version','full') from sysmaster:sysdual` ? the `charindex` function is available only at version 11.70. (at version 11.70 you can use the [`substring_index`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_2337.htm) for this too). If you are working with an older version, so, will need create a procedure to execute your *cut*

Comment: I am using a lower version. Can you tell me any other way this could be done instead of using charindex? Can you provide me with the syntax pls

Comment: Which lower version are you using?  You probably shouldn't still be using it; versions 12.10 and 11.70 are the primary supported versions, and 11.50 is just about in support.  No other versions are still supported unless you've made special arrangements with IBM. You can write a CHARINDEX function in SPL, but it is not going to be fast.

Comment: Here is my version #...IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.70.FC1GE.. I have tried substr() too. It gives me an error saying " Routine (charindex) can not be resolved." I tried substring_index() which would be perfect to this situation but it gives me an error too saying "Routine (substring_index) can not be resolved." Is it the version prob?? Is there a way to update it??

Comment: ok, my bad... this routines was added at 11.70xC3. Which means the third FIX (defects corrections, but IBMs always include new features with it). The current version/ lasted fix is 11.70xC7. You can check about this [news features here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.po.doc/new_features.htm)

Comment: About upgrade your engine, depends if your company have active support with IBM. If YES, just need download the last fix from [fix central here](https://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/) , of course will need an authorized user, plan the update of your database, which in this case is quite simple, long history short: just install new version, replace the configuration, stop the old version, start the new version... **WARNING** if this is a production environment, make sure will be done by an person with knowledge about this process.

Comment: About how create the procedure, check this [link](http://www.iiug.org/faqs/informix-faq/ifaq05.htm.1#5.11) where you will found the code of procedure what do the inverse what you want, just readapt the code... and if possible include here as your own answer.

Comment: FYI... Use `substr()` for older versions of informix  Ex: substr('abcde', 1, 2).  It looks like our older version of informix uses a 1 based index (ie. starts with 1 instead of 0)

Answer (score 4):

At first if you need to split such values and if you need to do it often then it would be easier to change your db schema:

1. rename column `name` into `last_name`
2. add column `first_name`

It has some advantages. You probably want to search employees by last name, and it is easy when you simply have such column. If last name is a part of `name` column then you must search using `LIKE` which is slower and worse.

Now you will have to change some data. If you have comma in `last_name` then in such column there is first and last name and you must split it.

If you have `charindex()` function you can do it with:

```
UPDATE employees SET last_name=substring(last_name FROM charindex(',', last_name)+1), first_name=substring(last_name FROM 1 FOR charindex(',', last_name)-1) WHERE charindex(',', last_name) > 0;
```

(you can also use `TRIM()` to remove spaces before/after comma which will be copied)

From comments I see that your version of Informix do not have `CHARINDEX()` function so you must upgrade db engine or use technique other than clean SQL.

If you can use programming language like Java or Python (for this example I use Jython: it is Python that work in Java environment and can use JDBC driver) you can:

```
db = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, usr, passwd)
# prepare UPDATE:
pu = db.prepareStatement("UPDATE employee SET last_name=?, first_name=? WHERE id=?")

# search for names that must be changed:
pstm = prepareStatement("SELECT id, last_name FROM employee WHERE last_name LIKE '%,%')

# for each record found remember its `id`, split `first_name` and update it:

rs = pstm.executeQuery()
while (rs.next()):
    id = rs.getInt(1)
    name = rs.getString(2)
    first_name, last_name = name.split(',')
    pu.setString(1, last_name.strip())
    pu.setString(2, first_name.strip())
    pu.setInt(3, id)
    rc = pu.executeUpdate()
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced a similar problem so I have developed a below function "char_cut" for informix 11.50 (haven't tried on different versions) Be warn that this is not the most efficient way to do that, but it works fine.

Usage:

```
SELECT
 char_cut(name, ',', 1) AS FirstName,
 char_cut(name, ',', 2) AS LastName
FROM
employee
```

Procedure:

```
create procedure char_cut( str_in varchar(255), separator_in char(1), field_in int  )
returning varchar(255) ;

define res varchar(255);
define str_len int;
define pos_curr int;
define substr_start int;
define substr_length int;
define pos_char char(1);

IF field_in <= 0 THEN return ''; END IF;

LET res = '';
LET substr_start = 0;
LET substr_length = 0;
LET str_len = length(str_in);

FOR pos_curr = 1 TO str_len

   LET pos_char = substr(str_in,pos_curr,1);
   IF pos_char = separator_in THEN
      LET field_in = field_in - 1;
   END IF;

   IF field_in = 1 and substr_start = 0 THEN
      LET substr_start = pos_curr + DECODE(pos_char,separator_in,1,0);
   END IF;

   IF field_in <= 0 THEN
      LET substr_length = pos_curr;
      EXIT FOR; --KONIEC 
   END IF;

END FOR;

IF substr_length = 0 THEN
   LET substr_length = str_len+1;
END IF;

IF substr_start = 0 THEN
   LET substr_start = str_len+1;
END IF;

IF substr_length < substr_start THEN
   LET substr_length = 0;
ELSE
   LET substr_length = substr_length - substr_start;
END IF;

RETURN NVL(substring ( str_in from substr_start for substr_length ),'');

end procedure;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ",", 1) as FirstName,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ",", -1) as LasstName
FROM
 employee
```

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=functions-substring-index-function